# Get the lastest record from the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query which gives me 5 records in the `sql`, but I want to show one record which is latest one.

Below is my query

```
Select a.mkey, c.type_desc DOC_TYPE, a.doc_no INWARD_NO,  
 convert(varchar, a.doc_date,103)date, 
 a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, d.type_desc DEPT_RECEIVED,  b.first_name    + ' ' + 
 b.last_name EMP_RECEIVED, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME, 
 b.email 
  from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a , user_mst b ,type_mst_a c,
    type_mst_a d 
 where a.to_user = b.mkey  and a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  
 and a.dept_received = d.Master_mkey   and a.to_user = '1260'
```

Below is the result

[![Query][1]][1]

I am using `sql-server-2005`

I tried with `TOP1` but it is not giving me the latest record

Comment: Use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY a.doc_date DESC`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: yes that worked, I missed the order by part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an `ORDER BY` in your query. Without the `ORDER BY` clause, there is no guarantee that the `TOP` command will return the expected result:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    <column_list>
FROM ....
ORDER BY a.doc_date DESC
```

Additionally, you should [avoid using the old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: yes, u r right felix, can I ask one more question issue related to this ??

Comment: I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: It is not sending the latest record, any reason ?

Comment: How do you define latest record?

Comment: see what actually I want. I have a form in which I save one record into the database. so for that record only  I want to send mail. let me know whether u get it or no.

Comment: Is there a column to indicate that it's the latest inserted record? Perhaps a datetime field, or an identity column?

Comment: Try ordering by that instead.

Comment: is it like this `a.to_user = '1260' order by a.mkey desc` ? I tried this and it is working

Comment: @NK Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112479/discussion-between-felix-pamittan-and-n-k)

Comment: sorry went for meeting, come on chat we will discuss

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.mkey, c.type_desc DOC_TYPE, a.doc_no INWARD_NO,  
 convert(varchar, a.doc_date,103)date, 
 a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, d.type_desc DEPT_RECEIVED,  b.first_name    + ' ' + 
 b.last_name EMP_RECEIVED, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME, 
 b.email 
  from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a , user_mst b ,type_mst_a c,
    type_mst_a d 
 where a.to_user = b.mkey  and a.doc_type = c.master_mkey  
 and a.dept_received = d.Master_mkey   and a.to_user = '1260'
 ORDER BY a.doc_date DESC
```